# Make a python script executed with -m leave ipython open

Tags: python-2.7, ipython

I have a python project which I want to be able to start from the terminal and be installable trought pip, when it has finished running the startup script it should leave the ipython session open in the terminal or in the future in an ipython notebook.

To do this I created a **main**.py file that gets executed when I call 'ipython -m projectname' following the instructions at https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2014/09/15/python-apps-the-right-way-entry_points-and-scripts/.

This code correctly first runs the init of the module and the the **main** file. However after running the script it returns to the terminal without ipython active.

How do I make sure it does not close ipython?

And for a bonus question, how do I make this work with iPython notebook (i.e. run the startup script and imports and then start at the first line of an ipython notebook)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `ipython -i main.py` to leave ipython open.
2. Or embed ipython in your code

Comment: Your suggestion of using ipython -i main.py did not work as the file is not main.py but the __main__.py file in some module.

However it got me on the right track, by adding "ipython -im projectname" it works perfectly. Thanks